# Host a local html file in localhost using python alone

Tags: python, html, server, xampp, localhost

I am running a code on a remote server that periodically generates a "status" html(something like a tensorboard say) and stores it in a folder in the server. Currently I download the html file whenever I want to check the status. If I can host the generated html using python into the server's localhost:p1, I can simply view the html in my local machine using

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:p1:localhost:p1 servername
```

I know that people use xampp/wamp to put local html files in localhost. Is there a way to do this with python alone?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Python 3, go to working directory where the files are located.
Then run:

```bash
python3 -m http.server 8000
```

Now open a browser and navigate to [localhost:8000](http://localhost:8000).

---

For Python 2:

```bash
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. Anyway to download a whole folder when I have opened it using this method?

Comment: download by a click, or download by using a script?

Comment: Yeah, I want to download by click if possible. Else can I wget a folder?

Comment: yes you can, either wget, or requests library or urllib.. Try out some stuff yourself.;) The only way you will learn.